# Как для пользователя "Автор" добавить возможность редактирования записи с использованием плагина? - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Как для пользователя "Автор" добавить возможность редактирования записи с использованием TinyMCE? Насколько я понял, плагины для не-администраторов отключены? Я установил User Role Editor, отметил все возможные для Автора привилегии, но это не дало положительного результата.

Comment: `Насколько я понял, плагины для не-администраторов отключены?` - ничего подобного. Что за плагин-то? В нём источник проблемы.

Comment: Как я указал в посте, плагин - TinyMCE. Также поле "Вступление" отстуствует для автора. 
http://mepic.ru/view/?id=8c6ee263b212cd024c4192863376e921
http://mepic.ru/view/?id=b6bef188a68a1fb49e1eef81711a28c3
Так это выгляит у автора.
http://mepic.ru/view/?id=505922a05bf2c38446fb02e94b0a8507

Comment: TinyMCE - это редактор прежде всего. Потому я и не понял.

Comment: [Роль "автор" по умолчанию может редактировать посты](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles%20and%20Capabilities#Author). Но только свои. Дай юзерам роль "редактор" и будет тебе счастье (возможно не долго, но это другая история :) ).

Comment: Я понимаю, что свои посты. Но редактор, как и автор, не имеет возможности создавать/редактировать свои посты с возможностями TinyMCE.

Comment: Не говори ерунды. Что значит "с возможностями TinyMCE"? TinyMCE - это родной редактор ВП

Comment: Смотри. Вот так выглядит редактор Админа:http://mepic.ru/view/?id=8c6ee263b212cd024c4192863376e921
Так Автора: http://mepic.ru/view/?id=505922a05bf2c38446fb02e94b0a8507
В частности у Автора отсутствует то, что выделно красным http://mepic.ru/view/?id=b6bef188a68a1fb49e1eef81711a28c3

Comment: Те три кнопки, что обведены красной рамкой - от какого-то(ких-то) плагина(ов).

Comment: Да, его класс "mce-widget mce-btn". Не могу разобраться, почему для Автора этот блок, а также "Абзац" и "Размер шрифта" не выводится.

Comment: Причём тут класс. Его тоже добавляет какой--то неведомый ПЛАГИН И вообще исправь вопрос - покажи в нём последнюю картинку, чтобы было понятно о чем ты спрашиваешь.

Comment: Вот именно класс я и привел, чтобы определить этот плагин.

Comment: Чтобы определить какой плагин - нужно отключить все и включать по одному. ...Если так не понятно что там делается по этим кнопкам...